# jenkins.exe start : command not found

Tags: jenkins, command

hii all of sudden my jenkins startes to give me this error i tried reinstalling it but same error again. I t was working fine earlier. now the server is running im not able to stop it as it says command not found.

i tried to stop/start/restart the server but i was unable to do so. the server is continuously running i am not able to stop it.

I want to stop the server but none command is working i am getting same error again however i am able to use jenkins.
Please let me what should i do to stop the server and fix the error.

Comment: can you add jenkins.exe path in environment variable ?